# Xamarin flymenu cover iPhone status bar

Tags: xamarin

Code run at iPhone7 screenshot
[image]

Same Code run at iPhone8 sreenshot -> flymenu cover status bar
[image]

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlyOutPageDemo"
            xmlns:localC="clr-namespace:FlyOutPageDemo.PageCollect"
             x:Class="FlyOutPageDemo.MainPage">
    <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <local:flyOutMenuPage x:Name="flyMenu"/>
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <localC:Home/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace FlyOutPageDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage : FlyoutPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            flyMenu.listView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;
        }

        private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item=e.SelectedItem as FlyOutItemPage;
            if (item!=null)
            {
                Detail=new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetPage));
                flyMenu.listView.SelectedItem = null;
                IsPresented=false;   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

flyOutMenuPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlyOutPageDemo"
             xmlns:localCol="clr-namespace:FlyOutPageDemo.PageCollect"
             x:Class="FlyOutPageDemo.flyOutMenuPage"
             Title="Fly out Menu">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="listView" x:FieldModifier="public">
                <ListView.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:FlyOutItemPage}">
                        <local:FlyOutItemPage Title="Home" IconSource="home.png" TargetPage="{x:Type localCol:Home}"/>
                        <local:FlyOutItemPage Title="Course" IconSource="course.png" TargetPage="{x:Type localCol:Course}"/>
                        <local:FlyOutItemPage Title="About" IconSource="about.png" TargetPage="{x:Type localCol:About}"/>
                        <local:FlyOutItemPage Title="Logout" IconSource="logout.png" TargetPage="{x:Type localCol:LogOut}"/>
                    </x:Array>
                </ListView.ItemsSource>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                            </Grid>                            
                        </ViewCell>                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

flyOutMenuPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace FlyOutPageDemo
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class flyOutMenuPage : ContentPage
    {
        public flyOutMenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

FlyOutItemPage.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace FlyOutPageDemo
{
    class FlyOutItemPage
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string IconSource { get; set; } 
        public Type TargetPage { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

above code run at iPhone7 screenshot
[image]
run at iPhone8 screenshot ->status bar cover flymenu
[image]

**Question: How to avoid Flymenu cover status bar ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually hide the status bar which will help avoid `Flymenu` cover it.

In your Xamarin iOS Application, edit and add following key-value pairs to the `Info.plist`.

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>  
<true/>  
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>  
<false/>
```